# Core 3 in project targeting Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Razor breaks cshtml Mvc views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

After setting TFM `to netcoreapp3.0` (Preview 7) in .csproj with target sdk set to `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Razor` compilation of cshtml views is broken, I get compile errors in cshtml files

`namespace Razor already defines Template`,
`ExecuteAsync() no method found to override`

When setting Sdk to `Microsoft.Net.Sdk` compilation completes successfully.

My goal is to get the views to compile into dll; the class library has to target both core 3 and net standard 2.0.
I am able to reproduce this behavior by creating an empty web app, adding a view and setting tfm to netcoreapp3.0

Is code generation indeed broken or am I missing something?